# Descobrir partição

Tags: java, arquivo

estou criando uma aplicação que será executada de um HD externo. Andei pesquisando mas não encontrei uma maneira sem usar muita gambiarra de encontrar a partição onde esse HD foi montado.

Meu objetivo é ter um objeto File que tenha como caminho a raiz da partição em que está montado o HD. Por exemplo: se o HD está montado em "E:\" (no caso do SO ser Windows), meu objeto File deve ter esse caminho.

Se alguém souber algo que possa me ajudar, por favor responda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu pensei em uma "gambiarra" aqui :p. Você poderia pegar o caminho completo em que a aplicação está utilizando o método [getCanonicalPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath()) de [java.io.File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), e depois filtrar o char da partição utilizando o método [charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) de [java.lang.String](http://java.lang.String). Elaborei esse pequeno exemplo para você testar. **Teoricamente**, ele deverá printar a partição em que a aplicação está sendo executada.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String applicationPath = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
        char partition = applicationPath.charAt(0);
        System.out.println(partition);
    }
}
```

Se quer a partição em que o sistema operacional se encontra, basta filtrar pelo caminho da pasta home (Multiplataforma):

```
char osPartition = System.getProperty("user.home").charAt(0);
```

Comment: Acho que ele quer o caminho do sistema operacional e não da aplicação.

Comment: Editei a questão incluindo como encontrar a partição do OS, @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Na verdade @GuilhermeNascimento, eu gostaria de pegar o caminho de onde a aplicação está sendo executada (HD externo). Quando plugar o HD eventualmente ele será montado em partições diferentes, queria pegar essa informação em tempo de execução. Me desculpe se não fui claro anteriormente.

Comment: @Marcel então a resposta do Ericson parece responder

Comment: @Marcel, o método getCanonicalPath que eu citei ali, retorna o caminho em que a aplicação está, independente da partição. Aqui ele retorna "E", porque o meu workspace está na E :p Não tem muito segredo, testa aí pra ver se funciona.

Comment: @EricsonWillians Obrigado pela resposta. Tinha pensado em algo parecido, minha relutância em usar isso foi que é uma solução específica para Windows. Imaginei que houvesse algum método da API ou de terceiros que oferecesse tal recurso (deixando a aplicação mais portátil). De toda forma agradeço a boa vontade, muito obrigado.

Comment: @Marcel, em ambiente Unix, você também receberá o caminho independente da partição em que está. A diferença é que o filtro da partição em relação a String não será o mesmo. A partição pode ser "/dev/hda1" ou whatever, terá de usar um Regex ou manipular a String de outra forma. Pra tornar multiplataforma, precisa reconhecer qual é o sistema operacional em que a aplicação está rodando. Você pode fazer isso checando o `System.getProperty("os.name")`. Porém, será chato pra testar :p Seus clientes usarão diferentes sistemas operacionais?

Comment: @EricsonWillians, na verdade a aplicação será para uso próprio (backup automatizado de arquivos pessoais - não necessariamente meus). Sou usuário Windows mas eventualmente uso Linux em uma máquina.